# Azure Machine Learning - Classification Clarfication

Tags: azure, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, classification

Hi,

Can someone please help me understand the results from the model (image) below? I am new to ML and checking if my understanding is correct that the model is 66% correct and not 83% in terms of prediction?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The metrics have different meanings, they are both correct, but if you wonder which one is more useful for evaluation, I think you should understand the difference between **overall accuracy** and **average accuracy**.

**Overall accuracy** : number of correctly predicted items/total of item to predict.

**average accuracy** : it is the average of each accuracy per class (sum of accuracy for each class predicted/number of class).

You could refer to the two articles, [1](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/eb31a252-8d84-4873-ad78-ceffc20b03b6/what-is-the-difference-between-overall-accuracy-and-average-accuracy) and [2](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-average-accuracy-and-overall-accuracy-in-a-confusion-matrix), they will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Read My Article which explain you parameters of classification Algorithm
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33879.classification-algorithms-parameters-in-azure-ml.aspx